# Programmatically assign different IP addresses to different OPC servers

Tags: c#, opc

I have to develop an application in C# that manages 4 OPC servers. The application will "create" and manage these 4 OPC servers (for the moment I think I wil use the the Wintech dll "WtOpcServer.dll" to achieve this, but not sure).

My question is : *If I have more than 4 Ethernet cards (so more than 4 IP adresses), is it possible to programmatically assign **each** OPC server to **each** Ethernet card ? (in order to have one IP adress **by** OPC server)*

I precise that I'm not obliged to use the Wintech solution, and any idea to achieve this are welcome.

Thank You for you answers

Comment: I'm interested in how you plan on going about doing this and what package you're planning on using. I've always used a commercial product (e.g. Kepserver or Wonderware).

Comment: I will probably use the commercial product Wintech WtOpcServer dll to achieve my project

Answer (score 0):

By "create" an OPC server I suppose you mean you're going to instantiate an OPC server in a remote host. The IP address of the OPC server is bound to the network configuration of each host. You don't necessarily need 4 Ethernet cards, e.g, all the OPC hosts may be in the same subnet.

There are a lot of options for connecting a C# application to an OPC server. Take a look at http://www.opcconnect.com/dotnet.php for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers ...

I finally ended by changing the architecture for my application. In fact, I will only implement **one** server that will contain all the OPC items that I need ( All the OPC items of the four servers I talked about in my precedent post).

I noticed that if I have 4 IP adresses in the machine that hosts the OPC server, each remote OPC client will be able to connect to the OPC server by using one of the IP adress of the server host.

That is sufficient in my case ...

Thank you for your answers though !

Comment: This is much more typical of how we use an OPC server.